# VS Code Extension: when relative path equals specific path in package.json

Tags: vscode-extensions

I am trying to create an extension for VS Code.
The purpose of the extension is to add a command in the context menu, so when the user right-clicks on a folder with a certain relative path the option shows up in the menu. If the user clicks on the option in the menu it starts a new terminal and runs a specific command.

I managed to solve the following:

- make the option show up in the context menu
- make it run the specific command in a new terminal

Now I want to restrict where the command shows up. I have the following structure:
`server_src/webaps/apps/<many folders here, each folder is it's own webapp>`

I want the option to show up **only when** the user right-clicks one of the webapp folders, ie when the path to the right-clicked folder equals `server_src/webapps/apps/MyApp`.

I have the following code in my package.json file:

```
  "contributes": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "command": "runfromcontextmenu.build&sync",
        "title": "Build & Sync"
      }
    ],
    "menus": {
      "explorer/context": [
        {
          "when": "explorerResourceIsFolder",
          "command": "runfromcontextmenu.build&sync",
          "group": "navigation"
        }
      ]
    }
```

My first thought was to add a condition to the following line: `"when": "explorerResourceIsFolder",`, for example: `"when": "explorerResourceIsFolder && resourcePath == '${workspaceRoot}/server_src/webapps/apps'",`

I've tried many variations of the above (both with and without the ${workspaceRoot} - I'm not even sure if ${workspaceRoot} is a real thing..) but nothing seems to work. The option stops showing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I don't think variable resolution is supported in a `when` clause.]

In any case, you can use something like this:

```
"when": "explorerResourceIsFolder && resourceDirname =~ /.*?[\\\\\\\/]webapps[\\\\\\\/]apps$/",
```

If you want you can add `server_src` to the beginning like:

```
/.*?[\\\\\\\/]server_src[\\\\\\\/]webapps[\\\\\\\/]apps$/
```

The `[\\\\\\\/]` is looking for path separators `/` and `\` which have to double-escaped here.

`resourceDirname` resurceDirname is a full path to the parent directory of the folder right-clicked on.  It is easiest to use the `=~` so that the right-hand side is treated as a regex and then look for the correct parent directories at the end `$`.